# Angular JS - Need to communicate with all directives on page from code in service which only runs once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a basic dropdown directive which works well (opening and closing correctly etc).

I have tried to create a manager service which keeps track of how many dropdowns are on thae page and allowes you to "close others" when a dropdown is opened and "close all" when the body of the page is clicked but not on a dropdown.

The trouble is that I want to put a single jquery event on the document body which calls the "close all" event and I only want it bound once. I can get this tow work if I put it in the factory method for the manager service, but from there it can't call a method of the factory being returned.

I also tried just closing them from the portion of code that wasn't returned from the factory because I have access to the array from there, but I don't have access to $scope.$apply from the service.

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Here is some code with most of it removed for brevity.

```
angular.module('directives')


.factory('dropdownManager', function() {

    var dropdowns = [];


    // Close all when the document is clicked, unless the click was on a dropdown
    $('BODY').on('click', function (event) {

        // NEED TO ACCESS CLOSE ALL FUNCTION FROM HERE

    });


    return {

        addItem: function(itemScope) {
            // Add Item to Array
        },


        removeItem: function(itemScope) {
            // Add Item from array 
        },

        closeAll: function(openItem){
            // Loop through array and close them all using item.isOpen = false;
        },



    };

}])

.directive('six4Dropdown', function (dropdownManager) {

    // Dropdown directive code goes here

});
```

Comment: You could put `ng-click` on `<body>`

Comment: No for events listening and triggers from service different than **directive**. Please consider to create directive on `<body>` element, listen for action than trigger event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by using a single .bind at the document level and used $rootScope to call dropdownManager.closeAll(); The key was getting access to the scope from inside that factory init code. The only way to do that seemed to be to use $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom directive for that reason please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.directive('myDirective', function(dropdownManager) {

  return {


    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          dropdownManager.closeAll();

        });


      });

    }


  };

});

app.factory('dropdownManager', function() {

  var dropdowns = [{
    id: 1,
    isOpen: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    isOpen: true
  }];





  return {

    addItem: function(itemScope) {
      // Add Item to Array
    },


    removeItem: function(itemScope) {
      // Add Item from array 
    },

    closeAll: function(openItem) {
      console.log("SA");
      angular.forEach(dropdowns, function(item) {

        item.isOpen = false;

      });
    },
    dropdowns: dropdowns




  };

});

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, dropdownManager) {


  $scope.data = dropdownManager;

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app" my-directive="">

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <pre>{{data.dropdowns | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That would work, but I wanted to bind a single event to the document, rather than one for each control. Thanks.